# Transition between uneven floor; reducer is wobbly

Tags: flooring

sorry if it's a stupid question. I self-installed some laminate and the flooring manufacturer provided some reducer transitions. I have two doorways where the new floor meets vinyl plank tile I am installing. There is about a 3 mm height difference, but the reducer is meant for a greater difference, and the height difference is also too great for a T transition. Any suggestions of what to do here?

TL;DR, floors are too uneven for T transition, not uneven enough for reducer.

Additional info: I am not equipped with the tools to manufacture my own custom transition, so if that's your solution please advise where I can get someone to do this for me! Thanks!

[image: Uneven flooring transition with reducer]

Comment: Hello, and  welcome to Home Improvement. You need a  different-shaped transition piece, which you could make or buy. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quite common scenario.  I ran the reducer thru a table saw to take off a bit of its thickness.  I tape it before cutting to minimize the chipping of the top coat.

I would be also interested in knowing how others deal with this because cutting this reducer isn't easy at all and I have broken a few in the process.

Comment: To be honest, this is pretty much what I ended up doing. Instead of a table saw, I got a carpenter to run it through a planing machine — he built a jig so that we could get it to exact size and then he ran it through. It came out beautifully. No chipping or anything, so maybe I got lucky. Seems to me that this might be the best solution for this if you're looking to use the manufacturer's transition pieces that match your chosen flooring.

Comment: Good to know that worked for you. I am now able to cut them quickly and with high success, but there is always a small amount of chipping.  Given it's on the floor, way far from eyesight, it looks acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

It just doesn't fit! I would suggest you measure every dimension of that transition very carefully, and make a rough profile drawing (pretty much exactly like your picture) to record what you measure. Take your drawing to some of the big box stores and possibly some specialty flooring places too, and see if you can match anything up (a caliper might be helpful). Those transitions are really tricky to deal with, so you might need to get creative.

You could try something like this:
[image: floor transition]

this will span the gap and handle the reduction, but you'll need some sort of shim to support it. For that, it might be possible to get a wood strip that fits in the gap area, or you could look for some sort of rigid, dense foam that you can cut with a knife.

The best solution is to find something that you like and that is close to fitting (what you have pictured would work perfectly) and cut it to size using either a table saw or a routing table. Of course, you'll either need to own the tool or have access to one somewhere. Both will require some feather boards and guides to get a clean and safe cut, but this way you are guaranteed a good fit.